# Ubuntu 18.04 cannot connect via SSH under VPN connection

Tags: ssh, 18.04, vpn, vpnc

On Ubuntu 16.04, I was connecting to a remote machine with Cisco VPN and SSH protocol without erros with the following commands.

```
sudo vpnc-connect /etc/vpnc/vpn.conf
```

with the following output:

```
VPNC started in background (pid: ...)
```

and then:

```
ssh -p 22 -X user@ip
```

After a clean isntallation of Ubuntu 18.04, while vpnc-connect command runs without errors when I'm trying to connect via SSH, it get stuck and finally raises "Connection closed by server_ip port 22" error..

My vpn.conf:

```
IPSec gateway <server ip>
IPSec ID ID_GROUP 
IPSec secret ID_KEY
Xauth username <USER>
Xauth password <PWD>
```

I tried the solution from here:
[18.04 VPN & UFW firewall issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028969/18-04-vpn-ufw-firewall-issue?rq=1)

but nothing changed.

Any ideas ?